# Do we have a template for a tag excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking through tags, I noticed that there are many different kinds of tags excerpt. A few examples:

> For questions about the Creality Ender 3 family of 3D printers

> Questions about the 3D printer firmware Marlin.

> when a logical or systematic search for the source of a problem in order to solve it is requested.

> helps to specify that the question is concerned with the material the print itself is made from. This includes 'filament' as a subgroup but also SL…

> should involve a 3D printer that is manufactured by Monoprice and branded by the name MP Select Mini 3D Printer v1/v2/pro.

I wanted to add excerpt to another tag, but it looks like there is no template for it. Each tag is written differently and it looks a bit messy. In addition, in many cases, tag excerpt is too long.

I have already read [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), but I would also like to know what should be the template for a tag excerpt?

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that there should be no more than two sentences in a tag excerpt, and ideally if it contains one short sentence. Something like this is a good example:

> For questions about the Creality Ender 3 family of 3D printers.

Tag excerpts should start with:

- For questions about...
- For questions related to...
- For questions regarding...

Tag description is a separate matter, in which there should be a more detailed description.

Comment: Good point about how to start the excerpt. It would be nice if they were all consistent. "For questions about..." is a good one. I'm sure that there is a meta question about this somewhere. I had a quick look earlier, but couldn't find the question that I was thinking about.

Comment: Let know if you find it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question, and *can* be difficult to answer.

It shouldn't be too long, as you have already noted, but it also should **not** just point out the obvious. That is to say, if the tag is [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament), then the excerpt should definitely not just be:

> For questions about filament

as it is not only obvious but also adds nothing that the name of the tag doesn't already provide.

I would suggest that it would be better to put:

> For *general* questions about filament used for 3D Printing. For questions about specific filament types, see the tags [pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pla), [petg](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petg), ... <and list the tags<sup>1</sup>>

Basically, if it is obviously what the tag refers to, then point out what the tag is *not* meant to be used for -  in order to prevent its misuse...

However, if the tag name is somewhat obscure then clearly it would be a good idea to spell out what it should be used for.

Clearly, the line between obvious and not obvious could be a bit of a grey area, and not distinct, depending upon the tag.

---

##### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> When listing related tags, make them *active UI elements* by using the appropriate markdown, like so:

```
[tag:filament], [tag:PLA], [tag:PETG], etc.
```

Comment: Good arguments. Simple excerpts are meaningless. Some info when to use this tag instead of others can also be useful. In your example, point 4. from question's link suits perfect and should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Yes, quite. Your [excerpt for stringing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16761) inspired me to post this answer. It seems a little bit obvious. However, off hand, I'm not quite sure what additional text would improve the excerpt..? Or even, if it needs improving. At least, your edit is better than it was, which was blank (I think, not sure). Anyway, thanks for looking into the tags, it is a job that needed doing :-)